# Windows 11 Notepad scrolling with mouse wheel lags behind

Tags: windows-11, scrolling, notepad

Scrolling vertically in Notepad on Windows 11 has a very noticeable lag when done with the mouse wheel. Scrolling with cursor up/down or page up/down keys is OK. Also dragging the scrollbar with the mouse is OK.

But if I scroll with the mouse wheel for example half of a page, then the content starts to scroll more or less normally, but comes to a stop only half second after I stop moving the wheel. In MS Edge it is similar, but there the scrolling is at least smooth. In Firefox the scrolling has no lag at all.

This started after upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 11.

Is there some setting to fix this for Notepad?

PS: Windows version is 22H2, up to date